# gtk_image in a gtk_button resizes the button in GTK3

Tags: image, button, resize, gtk3

I am using gtk3 and have put an image into a button using the following code snippet.

```
  GtkWidget *button1 = gtk_button_new();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (button1, 100, 60);
  gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (wfixed), button1, 20, 30);

  GtkWidget *img = gtk_image_new_from_file("handset-release.png");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button1), img);
```

The problem is that the button is not longer 100x60, instead, it gets resized to fit the image which is now larger in size.
This did not happen in gtk2 where the image would get cropped and the button would still remain 100x60.
I don't want the button to get resized.
Any reason why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me, it makes sense to fully display the image in the button. Why don't you crop the image itself before you pack it in the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the correct behavior and as @theGtknerd commented, you should have your images resized to the correct pixel size.

There are, however, several different approaches to get a result similar to the one you want, eg: load the image and resize it via GdkPixbuf (this will resize the entire image, at load or after), crop the image via subpixbuf (which will get a area at a point x,y with a chosen width and height. P(0,0) with a size of 100x60 is what you want)

The simplest way would be to add a GtkLayout "between" the button and its image child so that the button (which is a container) won't resize with its child size.

I've simulated both cases as shown:

[image]

The first window behaves like you requested and the second like it is now.
Note that you will have padding, border, horizontal and vertical expand and alignments, so you should tweak those to meet your needs.